# If you add files to the commit manually, why is .gitignore helpful?

Tags: git

I've been using git for a while, and I just don't see the point of a .gitignore file.

We have to stage changes before they are committed by using `git add foo.py` or something of the sort. However, even when I have a pattern in my .gitignore file instructing git to ignore .py files, it will still stage `foo.py` for the next commit.

So what's the point of a .gitignore file? Just so developers can be lazy with `git add --all` or `commit -a`? Am I overlooking some functionality?

Comment: _"even when I have a pattern in my .gitignore file instructing git to ignore .py files, it will still stage foo.py for the next commit"_ - gitignore does not work on files that are already tracked, that's why the change gets staged.

Comment: You seem to understand what .gitignore does so what is really the question here?

Comment: @1615903 You've obviously misread. I quoted `git add foo.py`, that doesn't mean it was already tracked. I'm aware .gitignore doe not work on files already being tracked.

Comment: @AlexMayle - in that case you're simply incorrect.  By default git will give a warning if you say `git add foo.py`, your .gitignore includes `*.py`, and `foo.py` is not already staged (and refuses to stage it without the `-f` flag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not just about being lazy.

Consider having **a big project** (for example some web application) in which you not only have source code but also a lot of user-specific configuration files (e.g debug / development, server settings, etc). You don't want to accidentally add that files to Git, each developer should have a config of their own.

And what if the directory structure is really complicated? For example if you're working with a few tools - let's take: Django, Angular, Protractor, Jasmine, Karma, Brunch (what is not uncommon) and you're jumping from one place to the other, it's hard for you to remember where you've made the changes. It's much more common to just add the whole outer directory to Git and don't care if something that shouldn't be there, will accidentally find its way.

**Edit (as per request)**

Another example of `.gitignore` usefulness is when you're using some intelligent IDE - like one from the JetBrains - and you're doing some re-factoring - like changing name of one function (which is used in 20+ files), it will edit that 20+ files. And changing one function's name might seem like too little for doing a commit right away. So typing about 30 files manually on the command line is a tedious task.

Comment: You could also easily remember the paths of the changes by using `git status` and then type the paths in with the tab autocomplete. I suppose I'm more scared of messing up a .gitignore file and letting things leak in with `git add --all` than I am of adding the ~5 files I edited per commit.

Comment: Well... Yes, in some simple cases. For example, if you're using some intelligent IDE - like one from JetBrains and you're doing some refactoring -for example changing name of one function (which is used in 20+ files), it will edit that 20+ files. And changing one function's name might seem like too little for doing a commit right away. Will you then type 30 files in the command line instead of git add --all?

Comment: Great example. You have lead me to the light. Put that in the answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Plus, don't you love to see those nice .project, .idea .classpath stuff accidentally get into your git project? Just add them to the .gitignore and then you can rest assured that if the files make it into git it's because a developer _willingly_ added them and not the result of an oversight.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's much simpler to just say: `git add .` and know that git will ignore the right files (plus developers are human and can make mistakes, even when adding them *manually*).

Comment: I would argue the converse. Adding them manually makes us silly humans less prone to making mistakes. I would never use `git add .` for anything but the most trivial projects. We shouldn't even be editing that many files per commit.

Comment: @AlexMayle that's ok for your use case and I'm glad git suites your needs. However I work on a large project and I know that if I did small changes on some files, i don't want to have to provide all the full paths for each file when calling git add. I only do ```git add .``` and then I start checking with ```git diff --cached``` and ```git status```. So by using .gitignore git is able to fulfill both your needs and mine.

Comment: @AlexMayle - you can argue the converse all you want, but you are empirically wrong.  If it's not in .gitignore and it gets generated in the repo's work tree, it *will* get accidentally committed before too long.